# Why is django ORM so much slower than raw SQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, query-optimization

I have the following two pieces of code:

First, in SQL:

```
self.cursor.execute('SELECT apple_id FROM main_catalog WHERE apple_id=%s', apple_id)
if self.cursor.fetchone():
    print '##'
```

Next, in Django:

```
if Catalog.objects.filter(apple_id=apple_id).exists():
    print '>>>'
```

Doing it the first way is about 4x faster than the second way in a loop of 100k entries. What accounts for Django being so much slower?

Comment: wow, this is very surprising

Comment: does something like `len(Catalog.objects.filter(apple_id=apple_id)[:1])` perform better?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically ORMs go to the trouble of instantiating a complete object for each row and returning it. Your raw SQL doesn't do that, so it won't take the penalty that incurs. For large result sets where you don't intend to use the object, it is better to bypass the ORM.

Comment: ORM is an acronym for "object-relational mapping."  It may be "trouble" to instantiate a complete object for each row, but that is the very essence of being an ORM,  Another questioner performed some tests and determined that Django 1.8+ has made greater improvements in performance comparable to the raw SQL way of doing things.

Comment: In this case we shouldn't have a large result set, if nothing else, ORM should put a limit 1 after the select...