# Django queries are 40 times slower than identical Postgres queries?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-debug-toolbar

I am running Django 1.7 with Postgres 9.3, running with `runserver`. My database has about 200m rows in it or about 80GB of data. I'm trying to debug why the same queries are reasonably fast in Postgres, but slow in Django.

The data structure is like this:

```
class Chemical(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=9, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Prescription(models.Models):
    chemical = models.ForeignKey(Chemical)
    ... other fields
```

The database is set up with C collation and suitable indexes:

```
                                   Table "public.frontend_prescription"
  Column       |          Type           |                             Modifiers
 id                | integer                 | not null default nextval('frontend_prescription_id_seq'::regclass)
 chemical_id       | character varying(9)    | not null
 Indexes:
    "frontend_prescription_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "frontend_prescription_a69d813a" btree (chemical_id)
    "frontend_prescription_chemical_id_4619f68f65c49a8_like" btree (chemical_id varchar_pattern_ops)
```

This is is my view:

```
def chemical(request, bnf_code):
    c = get_object_or_404(Chemical, bnf_code=bnf_code)
    num_prescriptions = Prescription.objects.filter(chemical=c).count()
    context = {
        'num_prescriptions': num_prescriptions
    }
    return render(request, 'chemical.html', context)
```

The bottleneck is the `.count()`. call. The Django debug toolbar shows that the time taken on this is 2647ms (under the "Time" heading below), but the EXPLAIN section suggests the time taken should be 621ms (at the bottom):

[image: screenshot of debug toolbar]

Even stranger, if I run the same query directly in Postgres it seems to take only 200-300ms:

```
# explain analyze select count(*) from frontend_prescription where chemical_id='0212000AA';

QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=279495.79..279495.80 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=296.318..296.318 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on frontend_prescription  (cost=2104.44..279295.83 rows=79983 width=0) (actual time=162.872..276.439 rows=302389 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: ((chemical_id)::text = '0212000AA'::text)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on frontend_prescription_a69d813a  (cost=0.00..2084.44 rows=79983 width=0) (actual time=126.235..126.235 rows=322252 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((chemical_id)::text = '0212000AA'::text)
 Total runtime: 296.591 ms
```

So my question: in the debug toolbar, the EXPLAIN statement differs from actual performance in Django. And it is slower still than a raw query in Postgres.

Why is there this discrepancy? And how should I debug this / improve the performance of my Django app?

UPDATE: Here's another random example: 350ms for EXPLAIN, more than 10,000 to render! Help, this is making my Django app almost unusable.

[image]

**UPDATE 2:** Here's the Profiling panel for another slow (40 seconds in Django, 600ms in EXPLAIN...) query. If I'm reading it right, it suggests that each SQL call from my view is taking 13 seconds... is this the bottleneck?

[image]

What's odd is that the profiled calls are only slow for queries that return lots of results, so I don't think the delay is some Django connection overhead that applies to every call.

**UPDATE 3:** I tried rewriting the view in raw SQL and the performance is now better some of the time, although I'm still seeing slow queries about half the time. (I do have to create and re-create the cursor each time, otherwise I get `InterfaceError` and a message about the cursor being dead - not sure if this is useful for debugging. I've set `CONN_MAX_AGE=1200`.) Anyway, this performs OK, though obviously it's vulnerable to injection etc as written:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "SELECT * from frontend_chemical WHERE code='%s'" % code
c = cursor.execute(query)
c = cursor.fetchone()
cursor.close()

cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "SELECT count(*) FROM frontend_prescription WHERE chemical_id="
query += "'" + code + "';"
cursor.execute(query)
num_prescriptions = cursor.fetchone()[0]
cursor.close()

context = {
    'chemical': c,
    'num_prescriptions': num_prescriptions
}
return render(request, 'chemical.html', context)
```

Comment: if you look carefully there is a diff in Bitmap Index Scan in both results, the two indexes are different

Comment: Thanks - that might explain why it takes 300ms in Postgres but 600ms in the debug toolbar's EXPLAIN. But it doesn't explain why it takes 600ms in the EXPLAIN but 2400ms in reality...

Comment: Null hypothesis: cache warming.

Comment: @joop - OK, I'm reading up on that now. I'm using `LocMemCache` right now. So in other words, the extra 5 (or 9!) seconds would be taken up by Django checking the local memory cache, finding nothing, and then storing the results in the cache?

Comment: First step of trouble shooting: try to separate. In your case: is it Postgres, or is it django? (but, I was thinking of a different kind of cache warming)

Comment: Just tried another page: 900ms in the EXPLAIN, 43 seconds in TIME. Whatever is causing this, it's making Django effectively unusable! :(

Comment: can you try deleting the following index: frontend_prescription_chemical_id_4619f68f65c49a8_like

Comment: also i just noticed that you are counting the no of rows, and slow count is a well know issue for postgres: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting

Comment: @AnkitPopli re your second comment - sure, but the raw Postgres count query is actually pretty fast, see the EXPLAIN above - it's slow in Django.

Comment: That data structure doesn't look valid. Did you mean "class Chemical" instead of "def frontend_chemical"?

Comment: @Richard my bad, it should be equivalent at least.

Comment: @joop - pretty sure it's not Postgres, since the raw queries are fairly fast.

Comment: @letitbee yes sorry. Fixed!

Comment: do you have slow http connection to your database? does django maybe have to wait for a connection to become available from a connection pool or something like that?  ...then once it eventually gets through the query runs in short time

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/databases/#persistent-connections

Comment: debug_toolbar is kinda intrusive and produces a lot of artefacts (which I suppose this is). If you open the same page with debug_toolbar disabled, what total time do you get? If it is <2s, probably toolbar itself is to blame.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes thanks, setting `CONN_MAX_AGE` seems to help a little bit.

Comment: @AnkitPopli tried deleting that index: seems to improve some calls, but the problem is still there, just loaded a page where the EXPLAIN says 720ms but the time was 32 seconds to load.

Comment: Is it is just that the ORM is much slower than raw SQL for big `COUNT` queries? Or is there something else going on? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696120/why-is-django-orm-so-much-slower-than-raw-sql

Comment: There shouldn't be such a difference in performance with and without ORM when selecting one row. Most of ORM's overhead comes from constructing objects. You mentioned that mostly queries that fetch a lot of rows show a slowdown, which makes sense, especially if you have debug_toolbar, which is a profiler. But you only shown us query with 1 result - the count(*). What about that? Also, have you tried disabling the toolbar? Does it make a difference?

Comment: Two thoughts. Is django running on the same computer as the database? If so, how many cores does the system have? Maybe it's context switching between django and postgres. Also, try changing the query to: ```num_prescriptions = Prescription.objects.filter(chemical_id=c.id).count()``` to avoid any potential joins that could be happening. Not sure if `count` trims the joins or not.

Comment: @letitbee sadly disabling the toolbar doesn't help...

Comment: @JoshSmeaton Django and Postgres are running on the same machine, it's a Macbook Pro with 4 cores. I'll try that change, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not reliable profiling code on your development machine (revealed in comments, all sorts of things are running on your desktop that might be interfering).  It's also not going to show you real-world performance to examine runtimes with django-debug-toolbar active.  If you are interested in how this thing will perform in the wild you have to run it on your intended infrastructure and measure it with a light touch.

```
def some_view(request):
    search = get_query_parameters(request)
    before = datetime.datetime.now()
    result = ComplexQuery.objects.filter(**search)
    print "ComplexQuery took",datetime.datetime.now() - before
    return render(request, "template.html", {'result':result})
```

Then you need to run this several times to warm up caches before you can do any sort of measuring.  Results will vary wildly with setups.  You could be using connection pooling that takes warming up, postgres is quicker on subsequent queries of the same sort, django might also be set up the have some local cache, all of which need spinup before you can say for sure it's *that* query.

All the profiling tools report times without factoring in their own introspection slow-down, you have to take a relative approach and use DDT (or my favorite for these problems: [django-devserver](https://github.com/dcramer/django-devserver)) to identify hotspots in request handlers that consistently perform badly.  One other tool worthy of note: [linesman](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/linesman).  It's a bit of a hassle to set up and maintain but really really useful.

I have been responsible for fairly large setups (DB size in tens of GB) and haven't seen a simple query like that run aground that badly.  First find out if you really have a problem (that it's not just runserver ruining your day), then use the tools to find that hotspot, then optimize.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that when Django runs the query, the data needs to be read from disk. But when you check why the query was slow, the data is already in memory due to the earlier query.

The easiest solutions are to buy more memory, or a faster io system.

Comment: Even if I got downvoted this is the most likely cause. Your database simply doesn't have enough memory. Try running the query with different chemical ids using psql. If the first query for given chemical id is slow, and later ones are fast, then the amount of memory available is your problem.

Comment: It's certainly the case that the first Django call to a given chemical ID is slow, and subsequent ones are faster. Isn't this more likely to be the effect of Django caching, though?

Comment: Nope, django doesn't do any automatic caching of database queries.

Comment: But Django will cache pages, as I understand it - I've got cache set to `LocMemCache`. So when I render the page in Django, it's possible that subsequent calls to the same page are coming from the local cache.

Comment: If django-debug-toolbar is still showing the query in the panel, then django page caching has nothing to do with it. Try disabling page caching and open the same page twice. Also, akaariai suggested that you run a new chemical_id query directly in psql twice - the first should be slow and the second should be fast.