# if condition on large querysets are very slow

Tags: python, django

I am using Python 2.7 and Django 1.9.2

I am trying to do a condition where if queryset is not empty, there will be a functionality. I realized something as my queryset has gone large up to 56,000 records. A simple condition with that queryset takes almost 5 seconds but if I added `.exists()` with the queryset it is just so fast.

Please check snippet bellow

```
from record.models import Record
records = Records.objects.filter(result=0)
if records:  # this takes almost up to 5 seconds with 56,000 records
    # do stuff here
```

With `.exists()`:

```
from record.models import Record
records = Records.objects.filter(result=0)
if records.exists():  # very fast abd just takes milliseconds
    # do stuff here
```

Any explanation why the first one is so slow? I'm beginning to think that the first one loops the value of the `records` variable when doing an `if`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you run `exists()`, it makes a quick and fast query to DB. As per documentation:

> This tries to perform the query in the simplest and fastest way possible, but it does execute nearly the same query as a normal QuerySet query

But, if you directly use the queryset in **IF** condition(or use `count()`, `len()` etc.), it gets [evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated). That is why it is slow. As per documentation:

> **bool().** Testing a QuerySet in a boolean context, such as using bool(), or, and or an if statement, will cause the query to be executed. If there is at least one result, the QuerySet is True, otherwise False.

Also, more on `exists()`:

> **exists()** is useful for searches relating to both object membership in a QuerySet and to the existence of any objects in a QuerySet, particularly in the context of a large QuerySet.

**But**, if the queryset is going to be evaluated anyway, then using `exists()` is not suggested because it will do more over work. In that case you can simply use it as `bool(your_qset)`.  As per documentation:

> Additionally, if a some_queryset has not yet been evaluated, but you know that it will be at some point, then using some_queryset.exists() will do more overall work (one query for the existence check plus an extra one to later retrieve the results) than simply using bool(some_queryset), which retrieves the results and then checks if any were returned.

For more details, please check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists).

Comment: But if I called `records` first then use `if records`.. It is fast

Comment: That time, the result it already cached. that is why its fast

Comment: When I called `records` itself even for the first time it is already fast. But calling `if records` for the first time is very slow.. Is there any other operations in the background going on?

Comment: Updated my answer with more details from documentation. Basically, when you call the records, then its evaluated, and results are cached. that is why `if records` is fast.

Comment: Sorry but I did not see the answer to **if records being slow**.. Is it because it looped to the queryset then check t he key address one by one if there is existing?

Comment: As per documentation: `bool(). Testing a QuerySet in a boolean context, such as using bool(), or, and or an if statement, will cause the query to be executed. If there is at least one result, the QuerySet is True, otherwise False.`

Comment: But when you checked the query time in my postgres it is just 300ms. But it took 5 seconds for the `if records` to be finished

Comment: Its converting SQL to Python Queryset objects, it will certainly take time.

Comment: But entering plainly `records` variable did not take time

Comment: Maybe you can look into this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696120/why-is-django-orm-so-much-slower-than-raw-sql